# Piecewise integral $f(x)=\begin{cases}x, 0\leq x \lt 1\\x-2, 1 \leq x \leq 2\end{cases}$

Tags: calculus, integration

I've got stuck on a simple exercise after reading the first chapter on integrals in Spivak's Calculus. Decide if $f(x)$ is integrable and calculate the integral:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x, 0\leq x \lt 1\\x-2, 1 \leq x \leq 2\end{cases}$$

From the graph of the function I see that it's clearly $0$.

Also one of the theorems seems to come useful: if $f$ is integrable on $[a,c]$ and on $[c,b]$, then it's integrable in $[a,b]$ and $\int_a^b{f}=\int_a^c{f}+\int_c^b{f}$ for $a<c<b$.

Let $c=1$, it would seem that $$\int_0^2{f(x)dx}=\int_0^1{xdx}+\int_1^2{(x-2)dx}=\int_0^2{xdx}-\int_1^2{2dx}=2-2=0$$

The definition of the integral given in the chapter defines it in terms of a function $f$ on a *closed* interval $[a,b]$ as the the common value that equals the supremum of the set of all lower sums and the infimum of the set of all upper sums. But here I have $f(x)=x, x \in [0,1)$, it's not closed and $\int_0^1{xdx}$ doesn't really make sense. At this point I don't know anything about integrals defined on half-open intervals. And $f(x)$ on $[0,1]$ is not $x$, but also $x-2$ at $x=1$.

How to approach this problem knowing only the definition of the integral and the basic theorems like that above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed,$$\int_0^2f(x)\,\mathrm dx=\int_0^1f(x)\,\mathrm dx+\int_1^2f(x)\,\mathrm dx.$$On the other hand, if $x\in[0,1]$, then$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x&\text{ if }x<1\\-1&\text{ if }x=1.\end{cases}$$So, on $[0,1]$, $f(x)=g(x)-2h(x)$, with $g(x)=x$ and$$h(x)=\begin{cases}0&\text{ if }x<1\\1&\text{ if }x=1.\end{cases}$$But Spivak proves, right after theorem 2 of that same chapter, that a function similar to $h$ is integrable and that its integral is $0$. So, since $f|_{[0,1]}$ is the sum of integrable functions, $f|_{[0,1]}$ is integrable too.

Comment: Makes perfect sense, thank you! Might be worth mentioning that g(x)=1 when x=1.